# Is it necessary to sign extend 0 bits in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl, modelsim

Simple 32-bit register:

```
    reg32 Reg_32 (
    .in(valueA), // input 32 bits               
    .clock(clk),
    .reset(rst),
    .out(valueB) // output 32 bits
```

However, `valueA` is defined as a 10-bit wire [9:0].

Does `valueA` need 22 extended 0 bits?

i.e.:

```
    .in({22b'0,valueA}), // 22 bits of 0 + value of wire [9:0]
```

or does the compiler do this in ModelSim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt it is necessary in most cases.  But, to avoid unpredicatble behavior due to different compilers, it is safer to explicitly pad the value to the correct width.  I would use replicated concatenation (as described in the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), for example):

```
.in ({ {22{1'b0}}, valueA}),
```